How can I record all my actions that I perform on vscode?
I want to record all my input actions from my text editor, as well as my vscode terminal there are extensions to do this.
I did research on vscode task and also on macro-command. I want to know how to record everything I do on vscode(my actions)  even my commands that I enter in the terminal in a file with the extension ". txt"
